# phpUnit test after redirect

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, testing

I am doing a number of test in zend framework for php.

in this test, after the user attempts an update they are redirected to a page.
the same page whether the update was successful or not.  I use a session to then give feedback to the user.

How do i test for this session variable?
or,
how do i use `assertQueryCount` after the redirect?
(i get the following error when i try `Cannot query; no document registered`.

thanks!